# Side effects of making a class abstract with the primary goal to prevent it from being instantiated?

Tags: java, abstract-class, private, encapsulation

I know the approach is to make the constructor private,
But why should we do it by making the method abstract,What are it side effects is my question?

Comment: Effects of what, making class constructor private or marking class as abstract ?

Comment: marking it abstract

Comment: "I know the approach is to make the constructor private" It really isn't... "What are the side effects of making the method abstract?" it destroys the concreteness of a class, and enforces that the method must be implemented in order for a derived type to be concrete.

Comment: no i ment making the class abstract

Comment: I want the bad effects and loop hole,preventing the class from being instaintiated was the primary purpose

Comment: @George Then ,what else is the approach to prevent an object from being created

Comment: **Why?** Java is an *Object Oriented* programming language, so what's the purpose of having a class being not insatiable? Are you sure you use the right language for your programming style?

Comment: If you don't want it instantiated, don't put it in the classpath, or better yet - delete it.

Comment: @Timothy We had it in exam

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Create a singleton object?  Manage creation of objects?  If so, then you don't need to make it abstract.  A private constructor will do.  Clarify what it is you want to do -- abstract may not be what you want.

Comment: We were asked to prevent a class from being instantiated in exam,Actual way was to make the constructor private,But i thought why not make the class abstract,and so i wanted to the side effects of doing so .

Comment: There are no side effects, it destroys the concreteness, that's it. And your exam is wrong(sort of, simply making c'tor s private is not a way to guarantee a class won't be instantiated), you can instantiate a class with only private c'tors if the class has a public static method. The difference between the two approaches is that one requires you to inherit the class in order to have a concrete type, the other can be used on a concrete type but disallows inheritance.

Comment: @ShashiTunga Greetings to your teacher: *dependency injection*, *encapsulation* and  *polymorphism* are much more important then consequences of making a class `abstract` for no reason...

Comment: `abstract class Private { /* can't instantiate me! */}`  Oh wait ...  `Private p = new Private() { };` ... I just did.

Comment: @Timothy i dont want the class to be instantiated but want to make the class inheritable and constructor should be accesable

Comment: So ... a `protected` constructor is what you need.

Comment: But we can create objects with protected contructor within the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: the question was altered heavily and thus I don't think my answer  really answers it anymore. Sadly I can't answer the new question as in further discussion in the comments it became clear that there seems to be some confusion.*

---

Turning the default constructor private will make it so other classes can not create objects of this class. Because how are they going to access the constructor function? They can't. But that doesn't mean you can not create objects of this class. The same way you can access private variables via a getter or setter function you could still create instances of this class. You just have to do it inside the class itself and distribute them to the outside.

An example of this is the Singleton design pattern. There you generate a single instance which you can access via a getter function.

---

An abstract class on the other hand can not be used to create objects at all. They are templates that are supposed to hold common data structures and functions. You can force the implementation of functions via abstract functions.

Comment: i dont want the class to be instantiated but want to make the class inheritable and constructor should be accesable , How to do this

Comment: @ShashiTunga Why are you so against making a class `abstract`?

Comment: i feel abstract isnt the way to do this.

Comment: @ShashiTunga Why? An `abstract` class is derivable, cannot be instanced but can have an accessible c'tor. Is there something you're not mentioning because right now `abstract` sounds like it'd be exactly what you need(from your description of what you need).

Comment: You must be confused with the terminology. Do you know that "instantiate" means "creating an object of a class"? You are asking (totally different to the main question btw) if you can create a class that does not allow the use of a constructor in any way but at the same time you want the constructor to be available.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen usage of using abstract classes where they define static factory method that creates default instance of that class which can either be public or private subclass of that abstract class. A quick example that comes to mind is `java.awt.print.PrinterJob`.

I have used the above example many times as Factory and a way to hide concrete implementations from being directly created by client code.

Another reason of the above example is to document that the class is not intended to be created directly but via its static factory methods.